# Using Spring AOP + JPA ( EclipseLink )

Tags: java, spring, jpa, aop

Is there a way to persist JPA entities from the Spring AOP advices? Whenever I try to do I get the error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError. I guess that might be caused because my persistence.xml configuration deploys the JPA infrastructure at runtime.

Spring configuration:

```
<aop:aspect ref="attachmentCreatorAdvice">
                <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* com.mycomp.core.eventhandlers.*.handle*CreatedEvent(..) )" id="attachmentCreatorPointcut"/>
                <aop:after-returning method="create"
                                    pointcut-ref="attachmentCreatorPointcut" />
</aop:aspect>
```

AttachmentCreatorAdvice code:

```
private AttachmentDao attachmentDao;

public AttachmentDao getAttachmentDao() {
    return attachmentDao;
}

public void setAttachmentDao(AttachmentDao attachmentDao) {
    this.attachmentDao = attachmentDao;
}


public void create(JoinPoint jp) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException  {

    Event event = (Event) jp.getArgs()[0];

    Field f = event.getClass().getDeclaredField("attachments");

    if (  f != null ) {
        f.setAccessible(true);

        List<Attachment> attachments = (List<Attachment>) f.get(event);
        Field id = event.getClass().getDeclaredField("id");

        if ( id != null) {
            id.setAccessible(true);

            AggregateIdentifier uuid = (AggregateIdentifier) id.get(event);

            for( Attachment attachment : attachments ) {
                AttachmentDto newAttachment = new AttachmentDto();
                newAttachment.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                newAttachment.setElementId(uuid.asString());
                newAttachment.setDescription(attachment.getDescription());
                newAttachment.setFilename(attachment.getFilename());
                newAttachment.setFilesize(attachment.getFilesize());
                newAttachment.setFiletype(attachment.getFiletype());
                newAttachment.setLink(attachment.getLink());
                newAttachment.setAttachmentBlob(DecodeUtils.fromBase64(attachment.getAttachmentBlob()));

                attachmentDao.save(newAttachment);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

attachmentDao is injected from Spring container. AttachmentDto extends from AbstractDto.

```
@MappedSuperclass 
public abstract class AbstractDto<T> implements Serializable {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean equals = false;
        if ( obj instanceof AbstractDto ) {
            AbstractDto o = (AbstractDto) obj;
            if ( o.getId().equals( this.id ) ) {
                equals = true;
            }
        } else {
            equals = false;
        }
        return equals;
    }

    @Id
    private T id;

    public T getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(T id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

When attachmentDao.save method is invoked I get the following error:

```
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2012-12-17 16:12:17.579--ServerSession(30266940)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--java.lang.NoSuchMethodError com.mycomp.core.data.dto.AbstractDto <init>
```

Hope that helps.

Cheers

Comment: please post code what you tried..where exactly u getting error

Answer (score 1):

The full exception stack trace would help, but the error seems like it may be related to JPA weaving.

This means your Spring config or usage is not correct, as the classes are not getting weaved correctly.  It could be that your superclass is not contains in your persistence.xml class list, or that it is being loaded before Spring calls the JPA weaver.

You could try disabling weaving in your persistence.xml (or just disable "eclipselink.weaving.internal"="false"), or using static weaving, or fix your Spring usage.

Comment: The code is working correctly in other scenarios, where aspects aren't used. I also suspect,that Spring poincut / advice bean initialization is done before the weaving of JPA entities ocurrs, so it can lead to this error. I'll try putting my superclass in persistence.xml config file. Thanks.